# How to run batch file on server and return result to client?

Tags: cmd

I have a bat file on server that return result, then I want to know can I run this bat file from my client and return result to my client?

e.g. Bat file return string value "Hello", I want to run this bat file from my PC and get string "Hello" display on my monitor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not mention if you would like to do this from code?  It sounds like PSExec might do what you require.

This is a short discription of what it does:

> PsExec's most powerful uses include launching interactive command-prompts on remote      systems and remote-enabling tools like IpConfig that otherwise do not have the ability to show information about remote systems.

It is free, and can be found here:
[PsExec v1.94](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx)

Hope it helps.

Comment: I want to run it from any external application, Thanks for your answer. PsExec is what I'm looking for.